# Regular expression for Apache url rewrite .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I would like to rewrite this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/i.php?photo=1234
```

to

```
www.mywebsite.com/i/1234
```

Can anyone help me with the right regular expression for `.htaccess`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^i/([0-9]+)/?$     i.php?photo=$1     [NC,L]
```

Remember to turn the rewrite engine on before you declare the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is make sure `Multiviews` is turned off, since you have a URI that is `/i/` as well as a script that is called `/i.php`. Multiviews and mod_negotiation will bypass mod_rewrite and your rules will get skipped.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^i/([0-9]+)/?$ /i.php?photo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And for redirecting links that are outside of your control:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+i\.php\?photo=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /i/%1/ [L,R=301]
```